# Difference between MockMvc and RestTemplate in integration tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, integration-testing

Both [MockMvc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html) and [RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) are used for integration tests with Spring and JUnit.

Question is: what's the difference between them and when we should choose one over another?

Here are just examples of both options:

```
//MockMVC example
mockMvc.perform(get("/api/users"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            (...)

//RestTemplate example
ResponseEntity<User> entity = restTemplate.exchange("/api/users",
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new HttpEntity<String>(...),
            User.class);
assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, entity.getStatusCode());
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

As said in [this](https://spring.io/blog/2012/11/12/spring-framework-3-2-rc1-spring-mvc-test-framework)
article you should use `MockMvc` when you want to test **Server-side** of application:

> Spring MVC Test builds on the mock request and response from `spring-test` and does not require a running servlet container. The main difference is that actual Spring MVC configuration is loaded through the TestContext framework and that the request is performed by actually invoking the `DispatcherServlet` and all the same Spring MVC infrastructure that is used at runtime.

for example:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("servlet-context.xml")
public class SampleTests {

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext wac;

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
  }

  @Test
  public void getFoo() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/foo").accept("application/json"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("Lee"));
  }}
```

And `RestTemplate` you should use when you want to test **Rest Client-side** application:

> If you have code using the `RestTemplate`, you’ll probably want to test it and to that you can target a running server or mock the RestTemplate. The client-side REST test support offers a third alternative, which is to use the actual `RestTemplate` but configure it with a custom `ClientHttpRequestFactory` that checks expectations against actual requests and returns stub responses.

example:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
MockRestServiceServer mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);

mockServer.expect(requestTo("/greeting"))
  .andRespond(withSuccess("Hello world", "text/plain"));

// use RestTemplate ...

mockServer.verify();
```

also read [this example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html)

Comment: where do you prepare mock entity with name `Lee`? I think `andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("Lee"))` validation will fail.

Comment: @naXa, these are integration tests, so we assume that corresponding data is stored in the database or populated before the test. Spring MVC Test "mocks" servlet container only but build application context with real beans, db connections, etc.

Comment: But, mockmvc can't handle custom exception(for testing negative scenario) which are stored in a file. It catched with "throws Exception" of Test Case function. How to handle this in MockMvc?

Answer (score 61):

With `MockMvc`, you're typically setting up a whole web application context and mocking the HTTP requests and responses. So, although a fake `DispatcherServlet` is up and running, simulating how your MVC stack will function, there are no real network connections made.

`RestTemplate` can conveniently be [initialized](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#%3Cinit%3E(org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory)) with a custom [`ClientHttpRequestFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestFactory.html). Implementations usually create `ClientHttpRequest` objects that open actual TCP/HTTP(s) connections. But you don't have to. You can provide a mock implementation where you can do whatever you want. In fact, this is how the [`MockRestServiceServer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html) utility operates, you could use that.

Answer (score 21):

It is possible to use both RestTemplate and MockMvc!

This is useful if you have a separate client where you already do the tedious mapping of Java objects to URLs and converting to and from Json, and you want to reuse that for your MockMVC tests.

Here is how to do it:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("integration")
@WebMvcTest(ControllerUnderTest.class)
public class MyTestShould {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void verify_some_condition() throws Exception {

        MockMvcClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new MockMvcClientHttpRequestFactory(mockMvc);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

        ResponseEntity<SomeClass> result = restTemplate.getForEntity("/my/url", SomeClass.class);

        [...]
    }

}
```

Comment: For my use case, I think this is the best approach since RestTemplate makes ORM mapping of the response much more straightforward when HATEOS (in particular) comes into play.

Comment: @fquinner, but it can't be rollback as it behaves like client and runs in different thread, rollback is not possible. You need to maintain another testDb then