# What's the correct way to write a Spring Boot Integration Test for REST API

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-boot-test

I have a `REST API` developed using `Spring Boot` and `H2 DB` which is working fine without any issues.

```
http://localhost:8080/api/employees
```

returns

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Jack"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Jill"
   }
]
```

Now the problem is that I have two different integration tests for testing this REST API. Both of them are working fine but I am not sure which one should I discard. I understand that both of them are more or less achieving the same result. The first one is using `MockMvc` while the other one is using `TestRestTemplate`.

Is there any best practice that I should be following and favoring one over the other?

**EmployeeRestControllerIT.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = TestingSampleApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class EmployeeRestControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void givenEmployees_whenGetEmployees_thenStatus200() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/api/employees")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name", is("Jack")));
    }

}
```

**EmployeeRestControllerIT2.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = TestingSampleApplication.class)
public class EmployeeRestControllerIT2 {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;
    private final TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();
    private final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    private final String expected = "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Jack\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Jill\"}]";

    @Test
    public void testRetrieveStudentCourse() throws JSONException {
        String url = "http://localhost:" + port + "/api/employees";
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, GET, entity, String.class);
        JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, response.getBody(), false);
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901985/difference-between-mockmvc-and-resttemplate-in-integration-tests?noredirect=1&lq=1 perfectly answers my question

Comment: did you find an answer to the question? There are thousands of articles, each is showing just hello world example, as if there is only a single api. What happens i try to test several apis, nothing on that.

Comment: @Imran - The answer is in the above comment's link that I have mentioned